# please explain me - xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);

Tags: javascript, ajax

In this code line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
```

what is the meaning of `gethint.php?q="+str` and why this is important?

Comment: the code is trying to get a URL , with q as a parameter being passed to this URL

Comment: its very basic Thing.As Your Code  you pass a value (have in Str) on the gethint.php page by GET method You can retrieve the value by $_GET['q']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here,

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
```

1. We are using ajax and xmlhttp.open is a method of XMLHttpRequest object.
2. GET is the request method.
3. gethint.php is the file on which you are sending request.
4. q is the parameter and its value is the value of variable str. You are passing data to gethint.php. You can receive value of q on gethint.php using $_GET['q'].
5. 3rd parameter is true, It is for async. If it is true, code after that request will be executed, If it is false, the code after that request will not execute until the request completed.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is you get the parameter q to gethint.php. This is important when you only want to get result without reload.

Comment: +1, I would also mention that `q` would be accessible from `$_GET[]` as any query string would be.